# Raster from grid shape

Tags: raster, r, grids-graticules

I have a .shp file from a grid. I read it and calculate the centroids. This data.frame has the latitude, longitude and some numbers in order making reference to the id of the grid's square. Something like that: 
[df-centroids](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NG6Te.png)

With this, I try to transform it to a raster where the values are the id (like they are different numbers I think it will work), but when I plot the raster it dont use the "id" like values, and in the data of the raster object I think the "id" field has dissapeared:
[rasterdf1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKlZJ.png)
 and the image after ploting that shows this: [plot(rasterdf1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpaex.png)

I dont know where I am wrong or where I am loosing the value field. Can anyone help me, please?

Here I leave my code:

`shapeData1 <- readOGR("C:/Users/b.vcm/Documents/rural_planner_dashboard_v2",'Grid_40Km')
    #The .shp I use
    trueCentroids <- rgeos::gCentroid(shapeData1,byid=TRUE, id=shapeData1$id)
    df_centroids <- data.frame(trueCentroids, id = shapeData1$id)
    spg2 <- df_centroids
    coordinates(spg2) <- ~ x + y
    spg2 <- SpatialPixelsDataFrame(spg2, tolerance = 0.286937, spg2@data) #tolerance is because coordinate intervals are not constant due to degrees distance
    rasterdf1 <- raster(spg2[,'id'])
    plot(rasterdf1)`

Comment: I don't think you are losing it, the values in the plot are the same as values(rasterdf1) - they are mostly NA, in the raster they are non-sparse. A raster doesn't behave like a data frame, but if you had other columns in spg2 you could keep them all with `brick(spg2)` - and then values() on that would be a matrix, x/y down the rows, fields along the columns.